# Hide , (comma) when tag is empty

Tags: angular

I have a tag like this `<div> {{ Hello }} , {{ Helo2 }} </div>`, I want to hide `,` when `Hello and Hello2` are empty. Can anyone help me in Angular4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Angulars  [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container)

> The Angular `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't
>   interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
>   DOM.

```
<div> 
   {{Hello}}
   <ng-container *ngIf="Hello && Helo2"> , </ng-container>
   {{Helo2}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom method `{{ join(Hello, Hello2) }}`.

Where:

> function join(val1, val2) {
>
> > var list = [];
> >
> > if (val1 && val1.length !== 0) list.push(val1);
> >
> > if (val2 && val2.length !== 0) list.push(val2);
> >
> > return list.join(",");
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
 `<div> {{ Hello }} <span *ngIf="Hello || Helo2">,</span> {{ Helo2 }} </div>`
```

Comment: If Hello or Hello2 -> show whole div. It's not what she want

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just put "," in span with *ngIf:

```
<div> {{Hello}} 
    <span *ngIf="Hello && Hello2"> , </span>
      {{Hello2}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can always invoke a function within your template literals.

```
<p>Hello {{commaSeperate("FirstName", "LastName")}}</p>

public commaSeperate(first, second){
  if(first == null)
    return;

  first = first == null ? "" : first;
  second = second == null ? "" : second;

  return `${second}${second && first ? ',' : ''} ${first}`;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugadmr

This will return:

`Hello LastName, FirstName` when `LastName && FirstName != null`
`Hello FirstName` when `FirstName != null && LastName == null`
`Hello` when `FirstName == null` *(doesn't make sense to greet someone by last name only.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p>Hello {{joinNonEmpty(", ", "FirstName", "LastName")}}</p>

    joinNonEmpty(separator, ...values) {
        return values.filter(x => x).join(separator);
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.